# Spring Container on App Service takes a long time to start

Tags: spring-boot, docker, azure-web-app-service, containers

I am trying to deploy a spring boot docker container on OpenJDK image into APP service on Azure. What baffles me is the time the web app takes on initial run (only during the initial run). I also see on the KUDU console that the container started up in less than 6 seconds but the APP service ran for more than 200 seconds and fails. Please see the attached screenshot. Has some one faced this issue before?
[image]

Edit 1: Adding the Docker File

```
FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim
LABEL Maintainer="Aravind"
VOLUME /tmp
ENV SSH_PASSWD "root:Docker!"
RUN echo "root:Docker!" | chpasswd

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl && apt-get     install -y --no-install-recommends dialog && apt-get install -y  --no-install-recommends openssh-server && apt install sudo
RUN useradd -m -d /home/spring spring && usermod -a -G spring spring

COPY sshd_config /etc/ssh/

RUN mkdir -p /tmp
COPY ssh_setup.sh /tmp
RUN chmod +x /tmp/ssh_setup.sh \
 && (sleep 1;/tmp/ssh_setup.sh 2>&1 > /dev/null)
COPY init.sh /usr/local/bin/

RUN chmod u+x /usr/local/bin/init.sh

EXPOSE 8000 2222
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
USER spring:spring
ARG DEPENDENCY=/workspace/app/target/dependency
COPY --from=build ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/lib /app/lib
COPY --from=build ${DEPENDENCY}/META-INF /app/META-INF
COPY --from=build ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/classes /app
EXPOSE 8080:8080
USER root:root
ENTRYPOINT ["init.sh"]
```

Comment: There is far too little information here to answer this. Check your database connections, database migrations, make sure your log-level isn't on TRACE/DEBUG/INFO. The container might have started that doesn't mean your application has started, it might still be starting. Check your application logs what is taking so long (generally database setup and migration is what takes a long time).

Comment: @M.Deinum the spring boot application doesn't have any database connectivity. It is a very simple API that proxy the inbound to another API doing some transformation on the fly. There is nothing that inhibits boot up like DB connection or any other acquired connections.

Comment: How should we know you didn't explain that as there is far too little information. Just an unreadable partial screenshot of logging. So without knowing what your app looks like or what it is doing this is just impossible to answer, if possible to answer at all as it depends on your environemnt as well.

Comment: Well, now that I explained what I am doing ( as in it is a plain spring boot API) think of it as a basic controller that returns a response. Do you have any suggestions to debug the issue?. Thoughts on why it is taking time to start?. I am fairly certain if you have tried that deployment you would have seen a flavor of it hence my main question ends with " have you seen it". I do hear your concern and I agree this is not a question you can answer with Spring boot knowledge alone.

I have been probing MS Support for 2 weeks + with no meaningful response. So am here as a last resort. FYI

Comment: Then provide more information. As stated there is far too little information.

Comment: How many time does it takes to your in your local environment? Can you post your `Dockerfile`?

Comment: @hackerman it takes exactly the same time (6. x s in local as well)as the kudu log says. Here is the Docker file. check the edit in the main question, please.

M.Deinum when you say add more details what should I add ?. I added the Docker file can you check if that helps ?.

Comment: @M.deinum added information, any more thoughts on where I can start ?.

Comment: Only a docker file, nothing on what is done on startup, how things are started (your `init.sh`, first thought entropy on the random but without seeing that stuff it will be impossible to answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after long research and help from MS support, Finally figured out the issue. As I said before, it is not related to how the container starts up as the container was starting up in less than 6 seconds.
The issue we noticed is that when the start up fails due to HTTP health-check timeout, the app is starting up with port 80 as the listening port. When it is successful, it starts up with port 8080.

Spring-Boot default listening port is 8080. The fix is to manually add the configuration for the APP service

```
App Setting Name:  WEBSITES_PORT
Value:             8080
```

The above configuration seems to have fixed the issue and now the time to start is the time taken by the docker container within the app service.